# menu sliding in from left - add top margin offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, mmenu

Is there a way to offset the menu in the options, vertically (in the Y position)?

I am sliding in the menu from the left in front of the page with the following:

```
   "offCanvas" : {
      "position"  : "left",
      "zposition" : "front"
   }
```

But, I want the menu to be about 200px from the top of the browser window.

I have tried adding a 'margin-top' - but for some strange reason, it moves the page as you go forwards/backwards to child menu's.

Any ideas / suggestions?

[JSfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/phil_joostrap/ch7d0pzp/)
--> I want the left mmenu to slide out below the orange bar. I was hoping there may be some sort of 'offset Y' that I could use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this should solve your problem:

```
$("#menu").css('top', '22%');
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/ch7d0pzp/3/) is a JSFiddle, in case you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about a mobile menu option but you can add this to your css to do what you want:

```
.mm-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 130px;
}
```